# OOP : Calculate average in an object

Tags: java

I am learning OOP in Java. I have an object which is named `Personage`with the following elements:

```
public class Personage {

  public String name; 
  public int note1;
  public int note2;


  public Personage(String name, int note1, int note2){
    this.name = name;
    this.note1 = note1;
    this.note2 = note2;

  }

  public void display(){
    System.out.println("Name : " + name);
    System.out.println("Note 1 : " + note1);
    System.out.println("Note 2 : " + note2);
  }

}
```

In the file Main.java, I have this:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Personage perso1 = new Personage("Eric", 7, 6);
    perso1.display();
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    Personage perso2 = new Personage("Sandrine", 8, 9);
    perso2.display();

  }

}
```

I would like to calculte the average for each personage. I know to do in procedural programming but I don't understand OOP.

I tried this ?

```
public class Personage {

  public String name; 
  public int note1;
  public int note2;
  public int noteFinale;



  public Personage(String name, int note1, int note2){
    this.name = name;
    this.note1 = note1;
    this.note2 = note2;
  }

  public int calculateAverage(String name, int note1, int note2, int noteFinale){
    int noteFinale = note1 + note2;
    return noteFinale / 2;

  }

  public void display(){
    System.out.println("Name : " + name);
    System.out.println("Note 1 : " + note1);
    System.out.println("Note 2 : " + note2);
  }

}
```

Main.java

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Personage perso1 = new Personage("Eric", 7, 6);
    int average = perso1.calculateAverage();
    System.out.println("Average => " + average);
    perso1.display();
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    Personage perso2 = new Personage("Sandrine", 8, 9);
    perso2.display();

  }

}
```

I don't understand the concept, in fact!!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why do you have parameters to your `calculateAverage` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you chose is not totally wrong.
I can list the errors that you made:

- It's ok to create a method called `calculateAverage()` but, since you've already created your instance of `Personage`, it has no sense to send again parameters that you already have as attributes of your instance (`String name, int note1, int note2, int noteFinale`).
- The code won't compile due to the previous error since, in the `Main` class, you have this line:

  `int average = perso1.calculateAverage();`.
   There's no method called `calculateAverage()` since the method you created has this signature:
   `public int calculateAverage(String name, int note1, int note2, int noteFinale)`.
- There's no need to create the attribute `noteFinale` just as and intermediate result for the average. Even if you need the sum of `note1` and `note2` for other purposes, values which can be calculated using *primitive* attributes, should be calculated and not stored as new attributes.
- The method is returning an `int`. Since the average could be a floating-point number you need to return a `double` (unless you wanted to return an `int` on purpose, by calculating a *floor* average).

So, the right implementation of the `Personage` class would be:

Personage.class

```
public class Personage {

  public String name; 
  public int note1;
  public int note2;


  public Personage(String name, int note1, int note2){
    this.name = name;
    this.note1 = note1;
    this.note2 = note2;
  }

  public double calculateAverage(){
    return (double)(note1 + note2) / 2;
  }

  public void display(){
    System.out.println("Name : " + name);
    System.out.println("Note 1 : " + note1);
    System.out.println("Note 2 : " + note2);
    System.out.println("Average : " + calculateAverage());
  }

}
```

If you know about these other corrections, I recommend using *getters* instead of having public attributes and overriding the `toString()` method for representing your instances of `Personage` as strings (instead of using `display()`).

Comment: Thank you a lot Nicola for your explanations. I understood, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Class Personage

```
  public int getAverage(){
    this.noteFinale = (this.note1 + this.note2)/2; 
    return this.noteFinale;
  }
```

Class Main

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Personage perso1 = new Personage("Eric", 7, 6);
    System.out.println("Average => " + perso1.getAverage());
    perso1.display();
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    Personage perso2 = new Personage("Sandrine", 8, 9);
    perso2.display();

  }

}
```

you can check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html if have doubts about main conceots of OOP in java

Comment: What if the user calls `getAverage` before calling `calculateAverage`? Better design IMO to combine the two methods into one that calculates and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you provided as a procedural code isn't wrong, but you should think if the act of calculating is a responsibility of the 'Personage'.

Let's imagine a supermarket, where you buy several products, who is responsible to give you the final price? The register? The product? So in this manner you should delegate the sum of the products to the 'thing' responsible for it.

In resume, put the logic for calculating the average outside of the 'Personage' Class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Personage {

  ...
  private double average;

  public Personage(String name, int note1, int note2){
    this.name = name;
    this.note1 = note1;
    this.note2 = note2;
    this.average = (double)(note1 + note2 )/2
  }
  ...
  public double getAverage() {
     return average;
  }
}
```

or

```
public class Personage {
    ...
    public double getAverage() {
     return (double)(note1+note2)/2;
    }
}
```

```
Personage perso1 = new Personage("Eric", 7, 6);
System.out.println("Average => " + perso1.getAverage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, `average` is going to be a derived member which obtains its value from the member variables `note1` and `note2`. You can define a method that computes the average from the values of `note1` and `note2`.

```
public class Personage{
//Other code here
    public int getAverage{
       return (this.note1 + this.note2)/2;
    }
}
```

Or, you can define a static `Function` which accepts in an argument of `Personage` and returns the average.

```
public static Function<Personage,Double> getAverageFromPersonage = (personage) -> (personage.note1+personage.note2)/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, your `Personage` class has two fields note1, note2. For calculating the average, now need a method, where you should implement average calculation logic. After calculation, you need to return the average value.

Average value will be a floating-point number so you should not declare integar type for the average value.

```
public class Personage {

  public String name; 
  public int note1;
  public int note2;


  public Personage(String name, int note1, int note2){
    this.name = name;
    this.note1 = note1;
    this.note2 = note2;
  }

  public double calculateAverage(){
    return (double)(this.note1 + this.note2) / 2;

  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not far off. One big principle of OOP, [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)), means that an object should know how to operate on its member variables, and hide that operation from outsiders.

### Hiding member variables

You're not far away from the canonical structure for a simple Java object, also known as a Plain Old Java Object ([POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object)). Your class should mark its instance variables as `private`, and make them accessible only through [getters](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp). This will make sure that each `Personage` instance keeps its business private, and that no other objects mess with it.

### Using the member variables

You are correct in making the average-calculating code a method of `Personage`. But as it stands, you code will not compile, because the `Personage` class does not have a `calculateAverage()` method, it only has a `calculateAverage(String name, int note1, int note2, int noteFinale)` method. The code in the the `calculateAverage` method already has access all of the member variables (`note1`, `note2`, and `noteFinale`). So you do not need to receive them again as parameters, you can use the existing member variables:

```
public int calculateAverage() {
  int noteFinale = note1 + note2;
  return noteFinale / 2;
}
```

### Letting the object initialize its own state

Another improvement that can be made to your code is that, assuming `note1` and `note2` will always be the same for a given instance of `Personage`, you can already calculate the average in the constructor. `calculateAverage()` could therefore be private, and be called as the last instruction in the constructor.

This makes the class "immutable", which means that once its state is set (in the constructor), it will never change. Another example of an immutable class in Java is `String`. This is a big help when it comes ot managing lots of objects and reducing bugs.

### Command query separation

Another principle that a lot of OOP developers follow is [Command Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation). This means that a method should either mutate the object (as in initializing a variable, or somehow changing its state), or return a value. What this means is that your code would be easier to reason about if you split `calculateAverage()` into two separate methods:

```
public int getAverage()
// and
private void calculateAverage()
```

As I am writing this, I can see that 5 other people have already answered you, so I'm sure you'll have lots to work with. The internet is replete with resources on OOP, from beginner to expert level. Here is [one](https://medium.com/@cancerian0684/what-are-four-basic-principles-of-object-oriented-programming-645af8b43727). For me, I got started with OOP by reading books on C++, and watching lots of Youtube videos. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Personage.class

```
  public int calculateAverage(){
   return (note1 + note2) / 2
 }
```

After, I highly recommend you should set property to private and access it with getter and setter

In main.class you're correct, but if you want to use multiple Personage, you should be use Collection and create Management class

good luck!!!